# Linq - SingleOrDefault and NerdDinner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm getting into LinqToSql and using the NerdDinner tutorial.

I'm trying to understand the syntax and would like to write out in more verbose fashion what is happening in the first line, which works.

Question:  How can I write the first query something like the commented out code (which doesn't work).

```
public Dinner GetDinner(int id){

        var result = db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DinnerID == id);

        //var result = from d in db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault
        //             where d.DinnerID == id
        //            select d;

        return (result);
    }
```

Cheers

Dave

Comment: I might be going against the grain here, but I have a strong preference for your current form. I find the declarative form hard to switch into when I use SQL so frequently (they're too similar but also very different), and so much of LINQ isn't covered in the declarative form that eventually (as you dig deeper) it makes more sense to go with method chains for consistency.

Comment: @spender - I too prefer the non-declarative form as I find  it more in tune with OOP and easier to read.

Comment: Many thanks to roufamatic, spender and Baddie (great name!).  I'll look at my linq queries so far and will try aiming for method chains.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a declarative version of `SingleOrDefault` that you can use.  Instead, wrap your declarative LINQ statement in parentheses like so:

```
var result = (
              from d in db.Dinners 
              where d.DinnerID == id 
              select d
             ).SingleOrDefault();
```